# CEA vs CNRS for permanent researcher positions in France

Tags: career-path, job-search, job, early-career, france

I am trying to find a permanent researcher position in France. I'm applying to job openings in [CEA](https://www.cea.fr) and [CNRS](https://www.cnrs.fr). Though I have some understanding of how CNRS operates and working conditions, salaries, etc, I have no experience at all with CEA.

For some context, [CEA](https://www.cea.fr) and [CNRS](https://www.cnrs.fr) are among the largest public research institutions in France (along with INRIA, INSERM, and some others).

What are the differences between the two institutions? In particular, what are the effects on the life of a researcher in terms of salary, funding opportunities, ability to attract students, career progression (i.e., how difficult it is to advance to director of research in CEA vs CNRS), and so on.

Comment: What are CEA and CNRS?

Comment: @Sursula I added some further comments to the OP. However, the question is intended for people who have some prior knowledge about this (hopefully there is at least someone in this forum).